# Routing traffic from GCP VM to VPC Native Cloud DNS GKE Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-vpc, gke-networking

I'm trying to achieve the following scenario:

My VM should be able to connect over a ClusterIP Service to the Pods behind it. The new beta feature here looks like this should be possible, but maybe I'm doing something wrong or misunderstood something...

[image]

The full documentation is here:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-dns?hl=de#vpc_scope_dns

The DNS is working, I get a service IP, a route to the default network is available.
I can connect via pod IP. But it seems the service IP is not routable from outside the cluster. I know, that normally a ClusterIP is not available from outside the cluster. But then, I don't understand why this feature exists and it also does not match with the diagram provided in the docs. As this feature seems to provide cross-cluster/VM communication via services.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-cip-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: load-balancer-example
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Do I understand the feature wrong or am I missing a configuration?

Traffic Check:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This only works with [headless](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) Kubernetes services.  So you'll need to modify your service spec to included `clusterIP: None`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-cip-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: load-balancer-example
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```